# C++ Text-To-Speech undefined errors

Tags: c++, text-to-speech, playsound

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream> 

char *sounds[] = {"d.wav","ai.wav","v.wav","i.wav"};

int main()
{
    char input[20];
    int k;
    int i = 0;
    std::cin >> input;
    while (input[i])
    {
        k = input[i] - 'a';
        PlaySound(TEXT(sounds[k]), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
    }
system("pause");
}
```

In an attempt to make a text to speech program, I have come across this problem.

int k, reads the input and plays the .wav file connected with the string that is read. The problem arises from `PlaySound(TEXT(sounds[k]), NULL, SND_ASYNC);`. The errors read: (**IntelliSense: identifier "Lsounds" is undefined**) and (**error C2065: 'Lsounds' : undeclared identifier**). Which both seem to mean the same thing, however, I can not find the source of the problem or whats causing it. How was/is Lsounds undefined and how would I fix it?

Comment: Where do you increment 'i' in your while loop?  Oh .. maybe in the macro?

Comment: There's tons of issues in this, not the least being that this approach of TTS hasn't been used in 25 years, for good reason. Every major OS comes with out of the box solutions already, and real ones, not like this. Also "wav" files :/

Comment: Yes, SAPI is an example of something that comes built-in. The easy way to solve this particular problem is to not try to support systems that old by using `TCHAR`-related utilities, and to pass wide strings into winapi functions instead.

Comment: An older method yes, but the attempt was so I could make a TTS program with a custom voice. I've messed with SAPI for a bit, but couldn't find a method that allowed me to use a custom voice. The .wav goes to one of 44 phonic sounds I made and edited. Would either of you know a place I could go to help learn/find a more piratical means of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's `TEXT(sounds[k])` that's causing the issue. `TEXT()` is a macro that expands to `L` followed by what you type inside, so that's the equivalent of `Lsounds[k]`, hence the error.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. Any idea how I might be able to work around this?

Comment: No idea what you're trying to achieve here. Like at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `PlaySound` API is used for playing WAVE files. You should use **SAPI** COM interface for TTS:

```
CComPtr <ISpVoice>  cpVoice;

//Create a SAPI Voice
HRESULT hr = cpVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  cpVoice->Speak(L"Hello World",  SPF_DEFAULT, NULL);
}
```

Comment: I used something similar once before, however, with this I can not use a custom made voice. PlaySound allows me to use 44 .wav files that hold all phonic sounds. Can I do something similar with SAPI? The ultimate goal is to use a custom voice.

Comment: You can create custom voice in SAPI. Search MSDN on that subject